# Looking for historical human population density data (USA)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, population

I often work with GPW (Gridded Population of the World) rasters, and I know for the US part they use the housing and population censuses.

However of the US census, I have only found census data for 1990, 2000, and 2010. https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/57753ebee4b07dd077c70868

While for GPW, they have 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020. This is odd because the USA part of the GPW is supposed to be based on the US census data?

Ideally, I'd need 1990-2020 data, one raster every 5 years, but from the same source.